# Set in a library and switches from live action to animation

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

All I can remember is that it starts with a boy who is in a library late at night. At first it's live-action, but then there are these animated colors (don't know how else to describe it) that flood the library. After that, the whole movie goes animated, with the kid having some sort of journey with characters from certain books.

I don't know if it's correct to say it was from the 80s, but its animation style was similar to that time, I think...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [**The Pagemaster**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110763/)

It has a boy that gets stuck in a library that then gets sucked into an animated world.  The beginning of the movie starts out a bit like so, before going animated, [**From wikipedia**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pagemaster)

> Richard slips on some water that had dripped from his coat and falls down, hitting his head and knocking him unconscious. He awakens and finds the rotunda paintings melting, forming a wave of color that transforms him and the library into illustrations.

The only thing that makes me doubt it, is the fact that it wasn't released until 1994, but I'm fairly confident the style was because it was being made for a while due to it being an animated feature.

Also, [**Here is a trailer of the movie**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u-gJr7iU6kI), to help show the movie in action.